# I get an extra lazy module, that has the name of the other two modules in it, separated with an ~

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have two lazy loaded modules:
- Tarjeta Oils
- Tarjeta Amarilla

When I `ng serve` I get 3 lazy modules. Also when I `ng build`
- {t-amarilla-t-amarilla-module}
- {t-amarilla-t-amarilla-module~t-oils-t-oils-module}
- {t-oils-t-oils-module}

I already tried taking them out of the empty folder they were in as suggested in this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9838), but nothing.

When I check `network` tab in developer tools. Each time I try any of the two routes, the combined lazy module get loaded together with the one that should load.

I have a `Core Module` that imports/exports `HttpClientModule`. It gets imported into the app.module.

My lazy modules just import their respective `Routing Module` and the `Shared Module`, no other imports.

app-routing.module

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

//Componets
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { InicioComponent } from "./inicio/inicio.component";

import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";

// Modulos
import { AuthGuard } from "./core/guards/auth.guard";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: InicioComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  { path: "inicio", component: InicioComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {
    path: "tarjeta-oils",
    loadChildren: "./t-oils/t-oils.module#TOilsModule"
  },
  {
    path: "tarjeta-amarilla",
    loadChildren: "./t-amarilla/t-amarilla.module#TAmarillaModule"
  }
];

export const Routing = RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  { useHash: true } //<-- para poder actualizar el navegador (prd)
)
```

oils-routing.ts/t-amarilla-routing.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import {
  TOilsComponent,
  TarjetaOilsReporteTendenciaComponent,
} from "./";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: TOilsComponent
  },
  {
    path: "tendencia",
    component: TarjetaOilsReporteTendenciaComponent
  },
]; 

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TOilsRoutingModule {}
```

And the Tarjeta Amarilla Routing Module looks the same as the oils routing module, just with the respective `tarjeta amarilla` components.

I have `index.ts` files everywhere, that's why the `import { ... } from '.'`

If you need any more info let me know.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I asked somewhere else and they told me that it was the `common chunk`, code that both modules share. Thus, normal behavior.